# Java swing, place marker at a location on an image in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I am trying to create a map application using Java Swing for a school project. There are several maps (in jpg format) which will be selected using a JComboBox, so I have a method to display a image in the JPanel (in JScrollPane) that takes in the image path, which changes based on JComboBox selection.

Right now, I have global variables x and y coordinates based on another JComBoBox selection, and I need to place a marker at the coordinates on the image. How would I do that?

```
public static void displayImage(String path, JPanel panel, JLabel label) {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    panel.removeAll();

    panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(image).getImage().getScaledInstance(1920, 1080, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))));
    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();
}
```

and in the main function for JscrollPane and JPanel:

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(245, 11, 1010, 659);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    label = new JLabel();

    scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
```

I have tried making a custom viewport and painting a marker on that, but it does not scroll with the image (the marker stays in the same location while the image scrolls)

Comment: Read about [JLayeredPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html). Put your Image and marker into `JLayeredPane`, and then this `JLayeredPane` in a `JScrollPane`.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy just what I was going to recommend

Comment: Thank yous for the reply! I will look in to JLayeredPane :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to place a marker at the coordinates on the image.

The code you posted has nothing to do with this "marker" that you are talking about.

> I have tried making a custom viewport and painting a marker on that, but it does not scroll with the image

If you want to do custom painting, then you need to do custom painting on the label (not the scroll pane).

1. First you would create a custom Object (Marker) with two properties: a) Image b) Point.
2. Then you would extend JLabel and add a method like `addMarker(Marker)`. The Marker object would be stored in an ArrayList
3. Then you would override the paintComponent() method of the label to a) invoke super.paintComponent(...) to paint the image. b) then iterate through the ArrayList to paint each Marker object.

Or the other approach is to add a JLabel object for each marker image to the main JLabel. The basic steps would be:

1. Create the JLabel with the image
2. Use setSize( markerLabel.getPreferredSize() );
3. Set the bounds of the marker label
4. Add the marker label to the background image label.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! The JLabel method worked like a charm!